# Connection problems with Rails and MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I was making some tests here on *Rails* and for first time I decide to use *MySQL*, I've setting up the gem *mysql2* and the *mysql server*.

When I try to access the database I receive this:

> ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

The strange thing is I'm able to run the *rake db:create* and the *migrations* without any problems.

thanks in advance,
Renan

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

Raised when connection to the database could not been established (for example when connection= is given a nil object).

Try checking your db configurations in the config/database.yml file if everything is correct or not!!